# how can i create input a box which shows bold and italic and ll things after posting

Tags: javascript, html, css

[ref.Post Box Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Trw3Q.png)

basically, I want to create this type of post box where user can customize their post.
but I don't know how to make it bold/italic/quote

Comment: Are you for looking for a little editor to add to your site? There are several out there. No need to invent the wheel or ask your users to learn a new way of marking up their text.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to provide your users some standard form of text parsing, Markdown has the features you ask for.

You can try using a markdown parser like these:

- [marked](https://github.com/markedjs/marked) ([demo](https://marked.js.org/demo/))
- [markdown-it](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it) ([demo](https://markdown-it.github.io/))

```js
const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
const content = document.querySelector('.content');
const update = () => content.innerHTML = marked.parse(textarea.value);
textarea.addEventListener('input', update);
textarea.value = '**Bold**  \n*Italic*'
update();
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

.container>* {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked/marked.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, can anyone tell me in short and simple way to use markdown in my text area

Comment: @Raju Added simple snippet using marked which I took from the documentation.